# SSL not working

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, letsencrypt

I've a nginx server on aws ec2 instance. I've successfully setup ssl and config for ssl in my nginx.
If I check my ssl setup using websites like:

https://whynopadlock.com
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

I can see that ssl is working fine but when I open the website on my browser as https://example.com 
it is automatically getting redirected to example.com

Here is my config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  keepalive_timeout   70;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-MD5;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.tk/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.tk/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.tk/chain.pem;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;

  server_name  example.tk;
  # HTTP redirect
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name .example.tk;
      location / {
        return 301 https://example.tk$request_uri;
      }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean it gets redirected to example.com? Do you mean it redirects it to the HTTP version?

Comment: Yes, to the HTTP version.

Comment: @Fanatique any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Fanatique Okay. I just checked, my info.php page is loading fine on `https://example.com/info.php` so why not other pages?

Comment: I have edited your post to try to format it better. You'll get more help if you format properly. It's in a queue to be reviewed.

Comment: Why do you have a server block nested within another server block? I didn't know that would even work, and if it does I don't think it's a good idea. Are you actually missing a close bracket? Can you please check your config above is accurate, format it well, then comment and I'll have another look. Server blocks should be separate, with a server name and a listen inside it. I don't listen on 80 and 443 within the same server block, my listen 80 blocks all forward, my non-www 443 blocks have a forwarder and my www 444 block serves traffic.